# Prevent status bar from becoming double-height?

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar

I have an app that records audio constantly, even in the background. When the app is backgrounded, the status bar turns red and becomes double-height. I'm wondering

1. if there's a way that the status bar can stay normal when my app is backgrounded
2. if this way will get my app rejected from the App Store

Comment: ps: I apologize if this question has been asked before. I did try Googling it first but couldn't find anything answering it. I'd be surprised if I'm the first person to ask this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide the status bar, or to force it to stay normal while recording audio in the background, at least not if you want your app to be in the AppStore.

Comment: I don't want to hide the bar entirely, just prevent it from becoming red and double-height

Comment: @SpencerWilliams The answer is still the same